# How to add sum of object value and merge array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have array with nested objects, want to add sum of value and make an object in javascript.

```
const arr = [
{
  preliminary: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  substructure: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  superstructure: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  architectural: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  mande: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  externalwork: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
  miscorcontingency: {
    contract_value: 1000,
    planned_value: 500,
    balance_value: 500,
  },
},
{
  preliminary: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  substructure: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  superstructure: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  architectural: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  mande: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  externalwork: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
  miscorcontingency: {
    contract_value: 100,
    planned_value: 50,
    balance_value: 50,
  },
},
```

];

I have done for one object, so want do multiple object

```
const result = arr.reduce(
(obj, { preliminary, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    Object.keys(preliminary).map(
      (key) =>
        (obj.preliminary[key] =
          preliminary[key] + (Number(obj.preliminary[key]) || 0))
    ),
    obj
  );
},
{
  preliminary: {},
  substructure: {},
  superstructure: {},
  architectural: {},
  mande: {},
  externalwork: {},
  miscorcontingency: {},
}
```

);

console.log(result)

Here I attach the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/y1dx4b9f/70/)

I got out put for "preliminary" value. I need all of object mean needs to do dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my solution:

```js
const arr = [
  { preliminary: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    substructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    superstructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    architectural: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    mande: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    externalwork: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 }
  },
  {
    preliminary: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    substructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    superstructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    architectural: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    mande: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    externalwork: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 }
  }
];

let result = arr.reduce((out, cv, ci)=>{
    if(ci == 0) return out;

    Object.keys(cv).forEach(key => {
        Object.keys(cv[key]).forEach(key2 => {
            (out[key] ??= {})[key2] += cv[key][key2];
        })
    });

    return out;

}, arr[0] );

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Array.reduce()` several times in combination with `Object.entries()` to add the properties at the correct level in the structure, the end result should be as required:

```js
const arr = [ { preliminary: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, substructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, superstructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, architectural: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, mande: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, externalwork: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500, }, }, { preliminary: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, substructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, superstructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, architectural: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, mande: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, externalwork: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50, }, }]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return Object.entries(cur).reduce((acc, [key1, val1]) => {
        return Object.entries(val1).reduce((acc, [key2, val2]) => {
            acc[key1] = acc[key1] || {}; 
            acc[key1][key2] = (acc[key1][key2] || 0) + val2;
            return acc;
        }, acc)
    }, acc)
}, {})

console.log('Result:',result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating an object accumulator

  - In every iteration, using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), iterate over the keys of the object at hand

    - Set `prev` to the the value of the key saved in the accumulator if exists, and `current` to the value in the object at hand
    - If no previous value was saved for this key in the accumulator set the object to it
    - Otherwise, using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over its keys and update the accumulator

```js
const arr = [
  { preliminary: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    substructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    superstructure: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    architectural: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    mande: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    externalwork: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 },
    miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 1000, planned_value: 500, balance_value: 500 }
  },
  {
    preliminary: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    substructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    superstructure: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    architectural: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    mande: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    externalwork: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 },
    miscorcontingency: { contract_value: 100, planned_value: 50, balance_value: 50 }
  }
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const prev = acc[key], current = obj[key];
    if(!prev) acc[key] = current;
    else Object.keys(current).forEach(k => prev[k] = (prev[k] || 0) + current[k]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    {
      preliminary: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      substructure: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      superstructure: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      architectural: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      mande: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      externalwork: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      miscorcontingency: {
        contract_value: 1000,
        planned_value: 500,
        balance_value: 500,
      },
      total: {
        contract_value: "7000.00",
        planned_value: "3500.00",
        balance_value: "3500.00",
      },
    },
    {
      preliminary: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      substructure: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      superstructure: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      architectural: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      mande: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      externalwork: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      miscorcontingency: {
        contract_value: 100,
        planned_value: 50,
        balance_value: 50,
      },
      total: {
        contract_value: "700.00",
        planned_value: "350.00",
        balance_value: "350.00",
      },
    },
  ];
  

const result = arr.reduce((obj, outerKeys) => {
  Object.keys(outerKeys).map((outerKey) => {
    // console.log(`outerKey:::`, outerKey);
    // console.log(`values[outerKey]:::`, outerKeys[outerKey]);
    // console.log(`obj:::`, obj);
    if (obj[outerKey]) {
      const tempObject = outerKeys[outerKey];
      Object.keys(tempObject).map((objKey) => {
        const tempInnerObject = obj[outerKey];
        tempInnerObject[objKey] =
          Number(tempInnerObject[objKey]) + Number(tempObject[objKey]);
        // console.log(`objKey:::`, objKey);
        // console.log(`tempObject[objKey]:::`, tempObject[objKey]);
      });
    } else {
      obj[outerKey] = outerKeys[outerKey];
    }
  });
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(`result :::`, result);
```

Comment: I think, it's an opportunity for everyone to look at other people logic and improve your logic building  :)